# добавление проекта к гредлу

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в ИДЕе добавить ранее сделанный проект к сборщику ГРЭДЛ? я пытался в ручную подложить файл build.gradle, но это не помогает. Иными словами у меня есть проект который я создал ранее и теперь я хочу его оттестировать с помощью грэдла. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Создайте новый пустой Gradle проект с нужными параметрами и скопируйте исходники существующего в нужные папки\пакеты.

Comment: Евгений спасибо, а можно подробнее, в какие папки и какие исходники ? я только учусь програмировать))